# Datagridview selected row cell returning null

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to get the value of the first cell (int type), of selected row in a datagridview but it returns null.

I want to use this value to write to add a new row to a different datatable

Here is the code I'm using:

```
membersDataGridView.Rows[membersDataGridView.RowCount - 1].Selected = true;
string memberID = membersDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: I can only assume that the `membersDataGridView`’s property… `AllowUsersToAddRows` is set to `true`. In that case. The first line of your posted code is going to set the grids “new row” as the first row in the grids `SelectedRows` collection… AND … All the cell “Values” on the “new row” will be `null`… therefore, when the second line of the posted code executes… it will throw a `null` exception since `membersDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value` will be `null`.

Comment: Therefore, if you want to get the info from the “last” (non-new) row in the grid… then, …. if the grid’s `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `true` (the default setting),… then,… the last (non-new) row in the grid would be at… `membersDataGridView.Rows[membersDataGridView.RowCount - 2]` … If the grid’s `AllowUsersToAddRows` property is set to `false`… then the last row in the grid would be at… `membersDataGridView.Rows[membersDataGridView.RowCount - 1]`. Also, there is no reason to “select” a row to get a cells value.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)